# Is there an idiomatic way to specify default values for optional parameters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, idioms

Is there a more concise and idiomatic way to write the following code, which is used to specify default values for optional parameters (in the params/options hash) to a method?

```
def initialize(params={})
  if params.has_key? :verbose
    @verbose = params[:verbose]
  else
    @verbose = true # this is the  default value
  end
end
```

I would love to simplify it to something like this:

```
def initialize(params={})
  @verbose = params[:verbose] or true
end
```

which *almost* works, except that you really need to use `has_key? :verbose` as the condition, instead of just evaluating `params[:verbose]`, in order to cover cases when you want to specify a value of 'false' (i.e. if you want to pass `:verbose => false` as the argument in this example).

I realize that in this simple example I could easily do:

```
def initialize(verbose=false)
  @verbose = verbose
end
```

but, in my real code I actually have a bunch of optional parameters (in addition to a few required ones) and I'd like to put the optional ones in the params hash so that I can easily only specify (by name) the few that I want, rather than having to list them all in order (and potentially having to list ones I don't actually want).

Comment: Perl now has the //= syntax to get around the problem of checking false values in this way. I know it doesn't help for this. That's why it's a comment, not an answer...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A common pattern is to use

```
def foo(options = {})
  options = { :default => :value }.merge(options)
end
```

You’ll end up with `options` being a hash containing the passed in values, with the options from your defaults hash as any that weren’t provided.

Comment: is there a reason to use plain `merge` over `merge!` ? (since i presume `merge!` would be faster)

Comment: @banister: Using `options.merge!(defaults)` would do the overwriting in the wrong direction.  You need to do `defaults.merge(options)` to overwrite the default valuess with the specified options.  And, since it would be awkward to store the result in 'defaults', you can't  use `merge!` and must instead assign the result back to 'options'.

I'm not sure if there is a huge speed difference between `merge` and `merge!`.

Comment: @Kelan, what? the code *is* equivalent to `defaults.merge(options)` since `{ :default => :value }` is `defaults` (though inline).

If you look at the code you'll see he's using `options` for both the parameter and the final hash. If you don't believe me, try it out. Using `merge!` is fine (I just did and it works exactly as you'd expect).

Comment: @banister:  Oh, did you mean to do `options = defaults.merge!(options)` instead of `options = defaults.merge(options)`?  Yeah, that works fine.  I was thinking before that you meant doing just `defaults.merge!(options)` and not assigning the result back to options...  So, I agree either way works.  As for performance, based on a little test I just did, using `merge!` is indeed about 40% faster.  So, your presumption was correct.  Good call!

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby 2.0.0** has a new feature [keyword](http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/10/08/keyword-arguments-ruby-2-0/) [arguments](http://dev.af83.com/2013/02/18/ruby-2-0-keyword-arguments.html)

Previously you had to write such code:

```
def foo(options = {})
  options = {bar: 'bar'}.merge(options)
  puts "#{options[:bar]} #{options[:buz]}"
end

foo(buz: 'buz') # => 'bar buz'
```

Now this is much cleaner:

```
def foo(bar: 'bar', **options)
  puts "#{bar}, #{options}"
end

foo(buz: 'buz') # => 'bar buz'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this

```
params = { :verbose => true }.merge(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write this, more succinctly, would be

```
def foo(options = {})
    options.reverse_merge! value1: true, value2: 100
end
```

This set options[:value1] to true (default value) unless options passed in already
contains the key :value1.  Same for :value2

Comment: To be clear, `reverse_merge!()` (and `reverse_merge()`) are specific to Rails (ActiveSupport) and hence not available in "pure" Ruby.